# ffmpeg stream rc buffer underflow

Tags: ffmpeg, stream, codec, ffserver

At the moment I'm setting up a screen-sharing platform with the opensource tool ffmpeg / ffserver. At the beginning of the sharing everything is fine. After around 1 1/2 minutes I get the following exception in the output.

`[flv @ 0x3a47aa0] rc buffer underflow
[flv @ 0x3a47aa0] max bitrate possibly too small or try trellis with large lmax or increase qmax`

I've tried to set an verry high lmax & qmax but this hasn't changed any thing.Additionally I've tried to increase the bitrate , the buffersize and the bitrate.

I use the following command with ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -f x11grab -s 1920x1080 -r 20 -i :0.0+1680,0 "http://localserver.de:8080/input1.ffm"
```

The config file for the ffserver is:

```
HTTPPort 8080
HTTPBindAddress 0.0.0.0
MaxHTTPConnections 2000
MaxClients 1000
MaxBandwidth 50000
CustomLog -

<Feed input1.ffm>
  File /var/ffserver/input1.ffm
  FileMaxSize 20M
  ACL allow *FROM IP*  *TO IP* 
</Feed>

<Stream screen1.swf>
  Feed input1.ffm
  Format swf
  VideoCodec flv
  VideoFrameRate 20
  VideoBufferSize 8000
  VideoBitRate 250
  VideoQMin 1
  VideoQMax 5
  VideoSize 640x400
  PreRoll 0
  StartSendOnKey
  NoAudio
</Stream>
```

An other streaming format would also be a possibility but I didn't know which are possible for live-streaming.