# ffmpeg and ffserver, rc buffer underflow?

Tags: ffmpeg, ffserver

I am attempting to write a simple streaming server for a project. I have an AWS Linux machine that will be running `ffserver`. Curently, as it stands, my config file looks like the following:

```
#Server Configs
HTTPPort 8090
HTTPBindAddress 0.0.0.0
MaxHTTPConnections 2000
MaxClients 1000
MaxBandwidth 1000
CustomLog -

#Create a Status Page
<Stream stat.html>
Format status
ACL allow localhost
ACL allow 255.255.255.255 #Allow everyone to view status, for now
</Stream>

#Creates feed, only allow from self
<Feed feed1.ffm>
File /tmp/feed1.ffm
FileMaxSize 50M
ACL allow 127.0.0.1
ACL allow <MY_PERSONAL_COMPUTER'S_PUBLIC_IP_HERE>
</Feed>

#Creates stream, allow everyone
<Stream tagLive.mpg>
Format mpeg
Feed feed1.ffm
VideoFrameRate 30
VideoSize 640x480
AudioSampleRate 44100
</Stream>
```

I then am capturing my Webcam and sending it up to the server using the following command:

```
ffmpeg -f dshow 
       -i video="Webcam C170":audio="Microphone (Webcam C170)" 
       -b:v 1400k  
       -maxrate 2400k  
       -bufsize 1200k  
       -ab 64k  
       -s 640x480  
       -ac 1  
       -ar 44100  
       -y http://<AWS_SERVER_PUBLIC_DNS>:8090/feed1.ffm
```

When I run this however, I get the following output from my console:

```
Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #0.1 : stereo
Input #0, dshow, from 'video=Webcam C170:audio=Microphone (Webcam C170)':
  Duration: N/A, start: 12547.408000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (YUY2 / 0x32595559), yuyv422, 640x480, 30 tbr, 10000k tbn, 30 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: pcm_s16le, 44100 Hz, 2 channels, s16, 1411 kb/s
Output #0, ffm, to '<AWS_SERVER_PUBLIC_DNS>:8090/feed1.ffm':
  Metadata:
    creation_time   : 2017-04-26 14:55:27
    encoder         : Lavf57.25.100
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp2, 44100 Hz, mono, s16, 64 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.24.102 mp2
    Stream #0:1: Video: mpeg1video, yuv420p, 640x480, q=2-31, 64 kb/s, 30 fps, 1000k tbn, 30 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.24.102 mpeg1video
    Side data:
      unknown side data type 10 (24 bytes)
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:0 (pcm_s16le (native) -> mp2 (native))
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:1 (rawvideo (native) -> mpeg1video (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[mpeg1video @ 02e95180] rc buffer underflow
[mpeg1video @ 02e95180] max bitrate possibly too small or try trellis with large lmax or increase qmax
[mpeg1video @ 02e95180] rc buffer underflow
[mpeg1video @ 02e95180] max bitrate possibly too small or try trellis with large lmax or increase qmax
[mpeg1video @ 02e95180] rc buffer underflow
[mpeg1video @ 02e95180] max bitrate possibly too small or try trellis with large lmax or increase qmax
[mpeg1video @ 02e95180] rc buffer underflow
[mpeg1video @ 02e95180] max bitrate possibly too small or try trellis with large lmax or increase qmax
[mpeg1video @ 02e95180] rc buffer underflow
[mpeg1video @ 02e95180] max bitrate possibly too small or try trellis with large lmax or increase qmax
[mpeg1video @ 02e95180] rc buffer underflow
[mpeg1video @ 02e95180] max bitrate possibly too small or try trellis with large lmax or increase qmax
[mpeg1video @ 02e95180] rc buffer underflow
[mpeg1video @ 02e95180] max bitrate possibly too small or try trellis with large lmax or increase qmax
[mpeg1video @ 02e95180] rc buffer underflow
[mpeg1video @ 02e95180] max bitrate possibly too small or try trellis with large lmax or increase qmax
[mpeg1video @ 02e95180] rc buffer underflowtime=00:00:01.13 bitrate= 404.8kbits/s dup=13 drop=0 speed=2.22x
[mpeg1video @ 02e95180] max bitrate possibly too small or try trellis with large lmax or increase qmax
[mpeg1video @ 02e95180] rc buffer underflow
[mpeg1video @ 02e95180] max bitrate possibly too small or try trellis with large lmax or increase qmax
[mpeg1video @ 02e95180] rc buffer underflowtime=00:00:01.63 bitrate= 361.1kbits/s dup=13 drop=0 speed=1.61x
[mpeg1video @ 02e95180] max bitrate possibly too small or try trellis with large lmax or increase qmax
[mpeg1video @ 02e95180] rc buffer underflowtime=00:00:02.13 bitrate= 368.6kbits/s dup=13 drop=0 speed= 1.4x
[mpeg1video @ 02e95180] max bitrate possibly too small or try trellis with large lmax or increase qmax
[mpeg1video @ 02e95180] rc buffer underflowtime=00:00:02.66 bitrate= 344.1kbits/s dup=13 drop=0 speed=1.32x
[mpeg1video @ 02e95180] max bitrate possibly too small or try trellis with large lmax or increase qmax
[mpeg1video @ 02e95180] rc buffer underflowtime=00:00:03.16 bitrate= 331.1kbits/s dup=13 drop=0 speed=1.25x
[mpeg1video @ 02e95180] max bitrate possibly too small or try trellis with large lmax or increase qmax
[mpeg1video @ 02e95180] rc buffer underflow
[mpeg1video @ 02e95180] max bitrate possibly too small or try trellis with large lmax or increase qmax
frame=  117 fps= 36 q=31.0 Lsize=     156kB time=00:00:03.86 bitrate= 330.5kbits/s dup=13 drop=0 speed= 1.2x
video:118kB audio:27kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 7.659440%
Exiting normally, received signal 2.
```

And on my viewer, I just get a black screen.

Is there something I'm missing? Searching lead to nothing on "increasing qmax" or anything similar to what `ffmpeg` complained about. There have been questions asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31827385/ffmpeg-stream-rc-buffer-underflow), but nothing has been done/answered.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set qmax and qmin in the server config

```
<Stream test_3840.flv>
...
VideoQMin 1
VideoQMax 15
...
</Stream>
```

More details can be found in that answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/18566361/4010173